# MDADM Raid6 Array only able to read parts of files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-raid

I run a ubuntu nas with raid6, mdstat does not indicate that anything is wrong, but when i try to read files on the raid volume, i am only able to read about 1/4 of the file, and the file transfer fails/freezes. I have tried multiple ways of reading files on the array (copy, ftp, http lamp server, but it always fail.  The same happens to every file i try to read.  The raid array have been running for months with no problems, and i cant seam to find what is wrong.  I hae also done a memory test which found no errors.  Could this be dead harddrives that have not been detected by mdadm?

Here is the output of mdstat:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid6 dm-2[1] dm-3[0] sdd1[4] sdb1[5]
      5860267648 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Have you reason to suspect raid, rather than say the file system?

Comment: @Paul  I have run an fsck test on the filesystem which came out clean... what do you suggest i check next? thanks...

Comment: If it is related to a kernel issue (raid, filesystem, memory etc), then you should get an error in `dmesg` - but did you have reason to think it was raid?

Comment: @Paul  Assuming raid was a bit of a jump to conclusions, but only due to the fact that only portions of the files were available, and the exact same amount was "missing" from each file... If it was related to file-system, i would assume that the unavailable parts were more randomly distributed... Memory problems was my first thought since the file reading process would freeze, but i excluded it after running memory tests for 48 hours. However, after leaving the server off for some time, it is working again now. But of course, the problem could still exist...  But thank you for your insights :)